# How to ignore to level directory in Git but not other directories starting with same name?

Tags: git

How to ignore top level `cache` but not 'apps/cache'?

I have such structure.

```
cache
apps/cache
conf/cache
```

I want to write rules to ignore only top level `cache`.

```
cache - IGNORE
apps/cache - NOT IGNORE
conf/cache - NOT IGNORE
```

How to do in git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just prefix the directory to be ignored with /. This will ignore the mentioned files/directories only in the directory where .gitignore is present.

**eg:**
   /cache

Comment: I tried it but it not works since `/cache` is not `/cache` but `/many_dirs_before/cache` in different systems prefix directories can be different - is not it?

Comment: @Chameleon In that case just provide the relative path from .gitignore to cache directory prefixed with /. If .gitignore is in root directory of your repo and cache is inside a directory named alpha. Then you should add  /alpha/cache in .gitignore file.

Answer (score 1):

Just provide the full path to your cache directory:

```
/cache
```

This way, things like app/cache and conf/cache won't be included.

Comment: I do not want provide absolute path since it is relative to system. Do you think it will work on different directory layout (yes or no)?

Comment: @Chameleon `/cache`is relative in the context of your .gitignore file.  So `/cache` will ignore the 'cache' directory that resides within the same level as your .gitignore.  Whereas `cache` will ignore all instances of 'cache', moving down the tree

Answer (score 1):

Note: the ability to anchor the path to the current folder of a git repo comes from [commit d0bfd02 (April 2007, git 1.5.2-rc0)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d0bfd026a8241d544c339944976927b388d61a5e):

> ### Add basic infrastructure to assign attributes to paths
>
> This adds the basic infrastructure to assign attributes to paths, in a way similar to what the exclusion mechanism does based on `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` and `.gitignore` files.
>
> Each line in these files defines a pattern matching rule.
>
> The first token on the line is a shell glob pattern.
>
> For glob matching, the same "if the pattern does not have a slash in it, the basename of the path is matched with `fnmatch(3)` against the pattern, otherwise, the path is matched with the pattern with FNM_PATHNAME" rule as the exclusion mechanism is used.

That is [why the documentation soon included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cedb8d5d33e6496cfc70493db841b3db886e8658#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R63) (June 2007, git 1.5.2.1):

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname;
> for example, "`/*.c`" matches "`cat-file.c`" but not "`mozilla-sha1/sha1.c`"